# OSGi: how to securely share connection between bundles

Tags: java, database, osgi, mariadb, osgi-bundle

I am trying to develop a java software based on OSGi (Apache Felix), which different module (which may contain more than one jar file) could be developed by different developers from different companies.

the question is: i am wondering how should i provide database connection to these modules. if i share the same user credential between modules, they may accidentally or intentionally use each other tables or data which should be avoid because of information privacy. or if i force each module to have its own connection with its own user credential then there will be many connections.

note: i am using mariadb as backend.

## i know this problem is not a OSGi specific problem. i am wondering if anyone has faced such problem and has proven solution for this scenario (i only describe my development environment).

any idea,

thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your issue of multi-tenancy isn't something any system (beeing it OSGi or not) is made for. Therefore you need to take care of this yourself. Most OSGi applications still use datasources if you want to connect to a db, via JPA for example. Usually those datasources are registered as OSGi services.

Coming back to your multi-tenancy issue, you should make sure for each you have another datasource and just use that datasource in your application. For example make sure each tenant has it's own configuration and therefore receives his own Datasource as configured in your configuration. This way you can make sure each tenant is separate to each other.

Answer (score 1):

OSGi cannot achieve the level of security you need for this scenario. An OSGi Framework is intended to represent a single logical application. If bundles exist in the same JVM and OSGi Framework, then it is very hard to prevent data leaks, especially against determined attacker.

You need to isolate processes at the very least, and run those processes as separate user IDs.